# UIImageView resize

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I've made a UIImageView with the correct size in the interface builder and connected the outlet up in the class file. How can I stop a large jpg from filling the entire screen? I want the image to resize to fit in the frame I made in IB.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wine" ofType:@"jpg"];  
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
    if(data){
        photo.image= [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

THANKS.

Answer (score 12):

In Interface Builder, select your UIImageView and open the Attributes Inspector (Command-1).
Change the View Mode to "Aspect Fit".

If you want to do this in code, set the contentMode of your UIImageView to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

Comment: You also probably want to set "Clip Subviews" to on, in the `UIImageView` properties.